# Matplotlib: Automatic coloured legend for all subplots using subplot line labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

The code below achieves what I want to do, but does so in a very roundabout way. I have looked around for a succinct way to produce a single legend for a figure that includes multiple subplots *that takes into account their labels*, to no avail. [plt.figlegend()](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figlegend) requires you to pass in labels and lines, and [plt.legend()](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) requires only handles (slightly better).

My example below illustrates what I want. I have 9 vectors, each with one of 3 categories. I want to plot each vector on a separate sub plot, label it, and plot a legend which indicates (using colour) what the label means; this is the automatic behaviour on a single plot.

Do you know of a better way of achieving the plot below?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nr_lines = 9
nr_cats = 3
np.random.seed(1337)

# Data
X = np.random.randn(nr_lines, 100)
labels = ['Category {}'.format(ii) for ii in range(nr_cats)]
y = np.random.choice(labels, nr_lines)

# Ideally wouldn't have to manually pick colours
clrs = matplotlib.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
clrs = [clrs[ii] for ii in range(nr_cats)]
lab_clr = {k: v for k, v in zip(labels, clrs)}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 3)
ax = ax.flatten()
for ii in range(nr_lines):
    ax[ii].plot(X[ii,:], label=y[ii], color=lab_clr[y[ii]])

lines = [a.lines[0] for a in ax]
l_labels = [l.get_label() for l in lines]

# the hack - get a single occurance of each label
idx_list = [l_labels.index(lab) for lab in labels]
lines_ = [lines[idx] for idx in idx_list]
#l_labels_ = [l_labels[idx] for idx in idx_list]
plt.legend(handles=lines_, bbox_to_anchor=[2, 2.5])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('/home/james/Downloads/stack_figlegend_example.png',
            bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: Example plot with 9 lines and 3 categories. Each category has a different colour]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to collect them using the label as a key. For example:

```
handles = {}

for ii in range(nr_lines):
    l1, = ax[ii].plot(X[ii,:], label=y[ii], color=lab_clr[y[ii]])

    if y[ii] not in handles:
        handles[y[ii]] = l1

plt.legend(handles=handles.values(), bbox_to_anchor=[2, 2.5])
```

You only add a handle to the dictionary if the category isn't already present.

Comment: Cheers. Didn't know that `k in some_dictionary` was equiv to `k in some_dictionary.keys()` either (i.e. that `if y[ii] not in handles` works)!